# OpenAM and Spring Security 4 Integration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, saml-2.0, openam

I am building a Spring-MVC-Hibernate back-end with dozens of RESTful web-services.   The front-end will probably be an HTML5, CSS3, and JQuery web-app that utilizes back-end web-services I am developing.

We have an OpenAM 10.x SSO system on a Tomcat server, and we want to us that for authentication, no authorization rules are here or groups.   All the documentation I have seen has been with an unknown version of OpenAM and Spring Security 3.  We have OpenAM 10.x with no known time to upgrade to the latest OpenAM.   We plan on using Spring Security 4.0.3, which is the latest at this time.

1) One way we can do this is to establish a Circle Of Trust, and then establish an IDP and a SP, and then we'll have a URL in order to do Federated SSO.  I believe this is how our front-end will get authentication and get a token returned to the front-end and may be stored as a cookie.

2) Another way I have seen this done is to simply call the OpenAM restful api, pass in username and password and get a token.  That token will then be used to pass into the back-end RESTful api's for security.

We will definitely be using Spring Security for Users, Roles, and Permissions (authorization), so can we do this?  Use Spring Security 4.0.3 for users, roles, and permissions, but use OpenAM for authentication???

Any information would be very helpful.   Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've been doing something similar with one of our applications. We started by using OpenAM 12 and we're now using OpenAM 13 SNAPSHOT.

We've been integrating using OpenID Connect though, not SAML.
This was a good starting point for us: https://github.com/fromi/spring-google-openidconnect.

We used the default header/basic scheme in OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails as opposed to form as in the sample.

On OpenAM, you'll have to configure OpenID Connect Provider.
Steps in OpenAM 13:

1. Login as amAdmin.
2. Select the realm.
3. The landing page (Dashboard/Realm Overview) will list common tasks.
4. Choose Configure 'OAuth Provider', then 'Configure OpenID Connect'.
5. Choose default values and click create.

Then you'll have to add an agent/client.
Steps in OpenAM 13:

1. From within the realm configuration page, choose agents.
2. Select OAuth 2.0/OpenID Connect Client.
3. Click on new button, enter client_id and client_secret values and create the agent.
4. Click on the newly created agent to further configure parameters such as redirect_uri, scopes etc.

If you cannot chose OpenAM 12 or 13 and are stuck with OpenAM 10, this information may not be useful.

Comment: Thanks so much for responding.   I've recently been told by my manager that we'll be going with OpenAM12 ... or whatever the latest is out there.  So, when I start this project, we won't have to deal with OpenAM 10,   Thanks again!

Comment: So ... after looking at various videos from SpringSource David Syers, it looks like we will be using Oauth2 from OpenAm 10 for now, and then later on OpenAM 12.   So, now I am looking for a spring-security.xml example for that, along with any other information I can find.

Comment: If you're looking at OAuth2, I'd just like to point out that OpenID Connect is an authentication mechanism build on top of OAuth2. The Auth in OAuth2 is for authorisation, not authentication.

Comment: This is all great to know, because I am definitely a newbie in this space, so I am trying to asorb as much as possible.   But let me ask ...since I know I can get a token from a RESTful URL from OpenAM 10 right now ... do you think it would be possible to configure a spring-security.xml file to use that?   That's really my next step ... I have all the jars pulled in, and now I just need to start configureing.   I know some like a Configuration class, but I am happy with the xml file.   Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Yes, you can use the RESTful APIs from OpenAM, but that kind of ties you to OpenAM. For us the whole objective really was to build our application to use a standard SSO technique like OpenID Connect (OAuth2), so that we can switch out OpenAM and use another SSO product (maybe something a client is already using) in place easily. And about the spring XML config, sorry, I don't have any references. BTW, this is something that I found really useful to understand the fundamentals: http://nordicapis.com/api-security-oauth-openid-connect-depth/